# Screencast Devtools Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ionic3, devtools, screencast

I am using devtools to debug Ionic 3 applications. I do not know what happens, but it does not allow me to touch my application through Screencast, I do not know if it is due to Ionic update, my smartphone (Android) or Google Chrome. The fact is that before, I could navigate through my application and now when I touch it does not do anything.

In case someone needs it:

```
- OS:            Windows 10 
- Chrome:        Version 72.0.3626.109 (Official Build) (64 bits) 
- Ionic:         3.9.2
- Smartphone:    Huawei P10 (Android 8.0.0)
```

Command used from Ionic CLI: `ionic cordova run android --livereload`

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/53826086/8850397